# Material Progress Bar for AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-html, dart-webui

Error: Package material_progress has no versions that match >=1.0.0 <2.0.0 derived from:
- your_next_startup depends on version ^1.0.0
app_component.html

```
 `<material-progress [activeProgress]="10"
               [secondaryProgress]="30"></material-progress>

 <material-progress [indeterminate]="true"></material-progress>`
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:your_next_startup/app_header/app_header.dart';


 @Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [
CORE_DIRECTIVES,
materialDirectives,
MaterialProgressComponent,
AppHeader,
],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `material_progress` package?. `angular_components` also contains a `material-progress` component.

Comment: Sorry and thank you so much. I was just little confused, I thought I need to import the dependency for using the angular_components progressive bar

Comment: No, the `material_progress` **package** was published before `angular_components` contained a `material-progress **component**. Now, as it's included in `angular_comopnents`, you only need to add this package in `pubspec.yaml` and import it from there.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you